# Putting HTML Table into ToolTip in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table

I've created a co-occurrence matrix that creates a tooltip when an occupied cell is hovered over. The code is as follows:

```
div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    width: 500px;
    color:white;
    padding: 8px;
    font: 13px sans-serif;
    background: black;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    pointer-events: none;
}

var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

function mousemove(d) {
      div
        .html("Tooltip is here")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")
  }

function mouseover(p) {
    div.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1);
    d3.selectAll(".row text").classed("active", function(d, i) { return i == p.y; });
    d3.selectAll(".column text").classed("active", function(d, i) { return i == p.x; });
}

function mouseout() {
    div.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1e-6);
    d3.selectAll("text").classed("active", false);
}
```

Then my elements call the functions mousemove, mouseover, and mouseout. This all works fine and the tooltip is displayed perfectly. What I want to do now though is generate a table when I hover over an entry, and have that table be inside the tooltip. The code I have right now generates the table properly, but it does not put it into the tooltip, instead the table is generated either above or below the matrix. I'm using this function to generate the table:

```
  function tabulate(data, columns) {
      var table = d3.select("body").append("table"),
          thead = table.append("thead"),
          tbody = table.append("tbody");

      // append the header row
      thead.append("tr")
          .selectAll("th")
          .data(columns)
          .enter()
          .append("th")
              .text(function(column) { return column; });

      // create a row for each object in the data
      var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append("tr");

      // create a cell in each row for each column
      var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
          .data(function(row) {
              return columns.map(function(column) {
                  return {column: column, value: row[column]};
              });
          })
          .enter()
          .append("td")
              .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

      return table;
  }
```

Could anyone give me some help on how I could get the table to generate inside the tooltip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently,

```
var table = d3.select("body").append("table")
```

Selects the entire body of your page and appends a table element, making the table appear appear at the bottom of your page.

Making a small change,

```
var table = div.append("table")
```

will take your tooltip element and append the table so it appears inside the tooltip. (naming the tooltip something a little more descriptive than 'div' might be a good idea)

Normally tooltip also need to update their contents when different elements are moused over; I don't think you're trying to do that here though?

Comment: Actually I am trying to update the contents when different elements are moused over. I think what you have given me works though. Every time an element is moused over I generate a table given the data from that element so it is dynamically changing.